# How to change dynamically numprocs in supervisor

Tags: laravel

I am using supervisor's `[program:x]` to keep my background queue runners up and running.

`numprocs` is set to a static number like 150, but now I am searching for a solution to dynamically adjust the process count depending on the workload of the queues.

Is it possible to change the `numprocs` value programmatically without affecting already running workers ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will fit your needs: https://github.com/wgjak47/supervisor_grace